# Sails + MySQL migration not working

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am pretty new to sails.js. I have an existing database and i tried to migrate it with sails.js using `migrate: 'safe'`. After that I have created a model by maintaining the same structure as db

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    user_id: {
        type: 'integer',
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    username: {
        type: 'string'
    },
    password: {
        type: 'string'
    },
    lastlogin: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    createdon: {
        type: 'datetime'
    }
  },
  autoPK:false
};
```

But in my controller when I tried to view these table values as below, nothing is displaying

```
viewUser: function(req, res){
    Auth_user.find().exec(function(e, r){
        return res.json({User: r});
    });
}
```

When I change the `migrate: 'alter'` and lift, it is showing error as
[image]

I would greatly appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Can you please remove the unique and required attributes of your user_id and test again.

Comment: Tried without unique and required attribute, still same.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by avoiding the auto field generation by using the below settings in model. Hope it will be useful for somebody else.

```
  autoPK:false,
  autoCreatedAt: false,
  autoUpdatedAt: false
```

I have tried with the values "migrate:" both 'safe' and 'alter' it worked fine.